# struts2 fileupload maximum file size

Tags: java, struts2

I'm using the fileUpload interceptor to upload files :). I've set a maximum file size as a interceptor parameter:

```
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
    <param name="fileUpload.maximumSize">20000</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Now, I want to get this value in my input/form jsp. To have a message for example "upload the config file (max. size 20kb)". How do I get this value? I can see that there is an instance variable FileUpload.maximumSize, but then how do I get instances of inteceptors in the stack?

tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to read your configuration file using the xml apis and get the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

http://cwiki.apache.org/WW/file-upload-interceptor.html